# How to make the other person reply to the chat message in xmpp?

Tags: android, client, xmpp, chat

I have used the following code to make the chat app in android.With the help of this code I'm able to send message to a client.But my need is to make the other person to communicate using my app.But currently it is not possible.The other person need to open his xmpp client window to see the messsages.How to create a session between two persons using xmpp.I saw many tutorials.They didn't help.So I'm posting a question here.

```
SettingDialog.java



 package org.apache.android.xmpp;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;

/**
 * Gather the xmpp settings and create an XMPPConnection
 */

public class SettingsDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    private XMPPClient xmppClient;
public SettingsDialog(XMPPClient xmppClient) {
    super(xmppClient);
    this.xmppClient = xmppClient;
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    getWindow().setFlags(4, 4);
    setTitle("XMPP Settings");
    Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    ok.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    //String host = getText(R.id.host);
    //String port = getText(R.id.port);
    //String service = getText(R.id.service);
    String username = getText(R.id.userid);
    String password = getText(R.id.password);
    String host,port,service;
    host="talk.google.com";
    port="5222";
    service="gmail.com";
  //  username="sabarish";
   // password="ramya";
    // Create a connection
    SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(500);

    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
            new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.1.4 ", 5222,"ubuntu");
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

    try {
        connection.connect();
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
        xmppClient.setConnection(null);
    }
    try {
        connection.login(username, password);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

        // Set the status to available
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        connection.sendPacket(presence);
        xmppClient.setConnection(connection);
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as " + username);
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
            xmppClient.setConnection(null);
    }
    dismiss();
}

private String getText(int id) {
    EditText widget = (EditText) this.findViewById(id);
    return widget.getText().toString();
}
```

}

```
xmppclient.java



  package org.apache.android.xmpp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.MessageTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class XMPPClient extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList();
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private SettingsDialog mDialog;
    private EditText mRecipient;
    private EditText mSendText;
    private ListView mList;
    private XMPPConnection connection;

    /**
     * Called with the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "onCreate called");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mRecipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.recipient);
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "mRecipient = " + mRecipient);
    mSendText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sendText);
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "mSendText = " + mSendText);
    mList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "mList = " + mList);
    setListAdapter();

    // Dialog for getting the xmpp settings
    mDialog = new SettingsDialog(this);

    // Set a listener to show the settings dialog
    Button setup = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.setup);
    setup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mDialog.show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Set a listener to send a chat text message
    Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String to = mRecipient.getText().toString();
            String text = mSendText.getText().toString();

            Log.i("XMPPClient", "Sending text [" + text + "] to [" + to + "]");
            Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
            msg.setBody(text);
            connection.sendPacket(msg);
            messages.add("You"+ ":");
            messages.add(text);
            setListAdapter();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Called by Settings dialog when a connection is establised with the XMPP server
 *
 * @param connection
 */
public void setConnection
        (XMPPConnection
                connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
    if (connection != null) {
        // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                    Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody() + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
                    messages.add(fromName + ":");
                    messages.add(message.getBody());
                    // Add the incoming message to the list view
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            setListAdapter();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, filter);
    }
}

private void setListAdapter
        () {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.multi_line_list_item,
            messages);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: Did You Got Solution ??